# A criterion for irreducible topological subspace

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a non-empty spectral space and $P$ be a closed subset of $X$. If $U_1,U_2$ are two arbitary quasi-compact open subsets satisfying $P\cap U_1\neq\emptyset$ and $P\cap U_2\neq\emptyset$, then $P\cap U_1\cap U_2\neq\emptyset$.

Can we deduce that $P$ is irreducible from the above conditions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, $X$ could have no nontrivial quasicompact open subsets at all (i.e., none besides $X$ and $\emptyset$), e.g. $X=[0,1]$.  Maybe you mean to additionally assume quasicompact open sets generate the topology?

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, I mean a spectral space! I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes (assuming $P$ is nonempty).  If $P$ were reducible then it would have a pair of disjoint nonempty open subsets, meaning there would exist $V_1$ and $V_2$ open in $X$ such that $P\cap V_1$ and $P\cap V_2$ are nonempty but $P\cap V_1\cap V_2$ is empty.  Now pick a point $p_i\in P\cap V_i$ and let $U_i$ be a compact open neighborhood of $p_i$ contained in $V_i$.

Comment: I forgot that $X$ is irreducible iff any two non-empty opens have non-empty intersection. Thank you!